# How do I decouple lamp from button using the dependency inversion principle?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, bridge, dependency-inversion

As per figure 5 in [DIP](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905081103/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf) I wrote the following code.
How do I write it to conform to figure 6 in the same document?

```
class Lamp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = "off"
    def turn_on(self):
        self.state = "on"
    def turn_off(self):
        self.state = "off"

class Button:
    def __init__(self, lamp):
        self.lamp = lamp
        self.state = "off"
        self.lamp.state = "off" 
    def on(self):
        self.state = "on"
        self.lamp.turn_on()
    def off(self):
        self.state = "off"
        self.lamp.turn_off()

lamp = Lamp()
button = Button(lamp)
assert lamp.state == "off"
button.on()
assert lamp.state == "on"
```

I am thinking of using the bridge pattern, but I am not sure how to write it. I am trying the following code but it still feels wrong to me despite the asserts running ok:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractButton(ABC):
    def __init__(self, button_client):
        self.button_client = button_client
    @abstractmethod
    def on(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def off(self):
        pass

class Button(AbstractButton):
    def on(self):
        self.button_client.on()
    def off(self):
        self.button_client.off()

class ButtonClient(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def on(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def off(self):
        pass

class Lamp(ButtonClient):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = "off"
    def on(self):
        self.state = "on"
    def off(self):
        self.state = "off"


lamp = Lamp()
button = Button(lamp)
assert lamp.state == "off"
button.on()
assert lamp.state == "on"
button.off()
assert lamp.state == "off"
```

Now inspired by Python protocols, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312739/if-condition-not-working-as-expected-in-java-class) I can write the following simpler code, that gets me a Button containing a Lamp Switchable device. There is only one place where the state is stored (the Lamp device) and I get controls on both for free.
But is this code decoupled?

```
class Switchable:
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device
        self.device.state = 'off'
    def turn_on(self):
        self.device.state = 'on'
    def turn_off(self):
        self.device.state = 'off'


class Lamp(Switchable):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__(self) 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Lamp {self.state}"

lamp = Lamp()
button = Switchable(lamp)
assert str(lamp) == "Lamp off"
button.turn_on()
assert str(lamp) == "Lamp on"
button.turn_off()
assert str(lamp) == "Lamp off"
lamp.turn_on()
assert str(lamp) == "Lamp on"
lamp.turn_off()
assert str(lamp) == "Lamp off"
assert button.device.state == "off"
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (btw, because python is dynamically typed, you almost get DIP for free).

Comment: Two things. One, the lamp has a interface for altering its state; `Button` should not be touching `self.lamp.state` directly. Two, there's no reason for the button to store state separately from the lamp it controls. Is there ever a case where `self.state != self.lamp.state`? If not, don't make it possible to represent such a case.

Comment: You still have `Switchable` delving into its `device`. <jaw drops>

Comment: I fixed the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the complicated inheritance design that is required when programming in C++. You can just simplify your first code snippet:

```py
class Lamp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = "off"
    def turn_on(self):
        self.state = "on"
    def turn_off(self):
        self.state = "off"


class Button:
    def __init__(self, lamp):
        self.lamp = lamp
    def on(self):
        self.lamp.turn_on()
    def off(self):
        self.lamp.turn_off()


lamp = Lamp()
button = Button(lamp)
assert lamp.state == "off"
button.on()
assert lamp.state == "on"
```

The three parts of the above can be in completely different files, with only the last part needing `import`s to get hold of the names `Lamp` and `Button`.

Comment: This shows composition is much better here than inheritance.

Comment: No, this shows that in this case, with python, inheritance is unnecessary and composition is sufficient. (Composition was always required for this kind of problem.)